# Передача массива с Data PHP/JS

Tags: javascript, php

Google charts для построение timeline требует массив данных следующего типа: `$chart_data['p'][] = ["1", "22", "new Date(2020, 8, 1)", "new Date(2020, 8, 3)"];`. Собираю массив в PHP. К сожалению если писать `"new Date(2020, 8, 1)"` в кавычках то скрипт не принимает данные. **Скрипт с которым работаю - ниже:**

````
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
        var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
        var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'pl' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
        dataTable.addRows([
          [ "plan", new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4) ],
]);

        chart.draw(dataTable);
      }```

 Как мне вписать ```new Date(1789, 3, 30)``` в массив создаваемый в PHP?
````

Comment: Заполнение массива следующим образом - не срабатывает. ```$dt_start = "new Date(2020, 8, 1)";
                $dt_end = "new Date(2020, 8, 3)";
                $chart_data['p'][] = ["1", "22", $dt_start, $dt_end];```

Comment: $chart_data['p'][] = array("1", "22", $dt_start, $dt_end);

Comment: к сожалению не помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы видимо пример для JS скопировали.
На JS это будет выглядеть так:

```
var b = { 'a': new Date(1789, 3, 30)};
JSON.stringify(b);
```

И в результате будет вот это:

```
"{"a":"1789-04-29T20:39:40.000Z"}"
```

Т.е. вам нужно на php собрать строку с датой и временем, чтобы получилось по формату аналогично `1789-04-29T20:39:40.000Z` такой строке.

```
$dt_start = date("2020-08-01\T0:0:0\Z");
$dt_end = date("2020-08-03\T0:0:0\Z");
```

Дату форматируйте как `date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z")`

Comment: Огромное спасибо, через форматирование даты предложенным вами выше получилось. Так же решается путем создания массива следующего вида: ```$startDate = new Datetime($time_start); // 2020-10-10 01:01:01

$data = array(
    'cols' => array(
        array('type' => 'string', 'label' => 'goalName'),
        array('type' => 'date', 'label' => 'starts'),
        array('type' => 'date', 'label' => 'finish')
    ),
    $data['rows'][] = array('c' => array(
        array('v' => $row['goalName']),
        array('v' => $startDate),
        array('v' => $finishDate)
    ));```